# UV Map offset issue

Tags: uv

I imported a character and it seems that there is an offset of the UV map (see below). I need this in order to bake normal maps with the identical uv mapping as the existing textures.

What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: In the UV editor menu, go to "UV -> Pack Islands". That's somewhat "short'n'nasty", but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortuantely, this seems to result in UV mapping that does not match the existing textures.

Comment: Which in conclusion means that the model itself has more than one texture/material (often done when in need of more texture space for the face). Remapping a new UV map to an existing texture is... well... a massive pita, 0/10 would not recommend. Either bake every part individually or use the "bake hipoly to lopoly textures" method by using the original model as the hipoly and a copy with a new UV map as the lopoly mesh.